# Testing nginx in a Docker container in on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-core, docker

1. Followed [Setting up Ubuntu Core on a KVM](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-local)

   - It shows you how to start the vm and forward ports back to your host machine.
2. Followed [Snappy Tour](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/tutorials/using-snappy/)

   - It shows you how to install Docker on Ubuntu Core
3. Installed the latest nginx image
4. Looked at [Managing Containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/) and interactively got nginx running in my container

Now the container is running nginx on a random port.

Back in Ubuntu Core, I tried to install wget or curl to return a page from nginx in my container but there isn't one either one listed in snappy search; how else can I test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nc (netcat) will do the trick.

```
nc 127.0.0.1 32771
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: netcat
```

32771 is the random port in my case,
a detailed explanation is available here:
[download a URL by netcat](https://superuser.com/a/506575/398219)

[image]