# Krita: Filling a whole selection or layer

Tags: krita

I need to fill a selection or layer with pure white. I couldn't figure out how I will do that. It's relatively easy to do via layer effects in Photoshop. But there are no layer effects.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Fill Tool

[image]

Fill a contiguous area of color with a color or fill a selection. Clicking anywhere on the screen with the fill tool will allow that area to be filled with the foreground color. You can select the foreground color from the Advanced Color Selector pane.

#### Fill Tool Options

Click the paint bucket fill tool icon in the Krita toolbox to show the Fill Tool Options pane in the upper right corner of the Krita window.

[image]

Threshold
⠀⠀⠀<sup>Determines when the fill tool sees another color as a border.</sup>
Grow/shrink selection
⠀⠀⠀<sup>This value grows/shrinks the shape beyond its initial size.</sup>
Feathering radius
⠀⠀⠀<sup>This value will add a soft border to the filled shape.</sup>
Fill entire selection
⠀⠀⠀<sup>Activating this will result in the shape filling the whole of the active selection, regardless of threshold.</sup>
Limit to current layer
⠀⠀⠀<sub>Use this option to fill the entire selection with the foreground color.</sub>
⠀⠀⠀<sup>Activating this will prevent the fill tool from taking other layers into account.</sup>
Use pattern
⠀⠀⠀<sup>Ticking this will result in the active pattern being used.</sup>

<sub>Some parts of this were revised from the [Krita/Manual/Tools/Fill webpage from KDE UserBase Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20160801084252/https://userbase.kde.org/Krita/Manual/Tools/Fill).</sub>

Comment: What if we have many selections like around letters in black on a white background? How can I fill all once?

Comment: Select all the letters in black with the *Select similar colors* tool (it's at the bottom row of the toolbox). Make a new blank image the same size as the current working image. Fill the new image with the background color that you want to be shown around the black letters using the Fill Tool. Copy all the black letters at once into the new image and merge down/anchor the black letters layer. Select whatever else you want to save from the original image and copy it into the new image and merge down/anchor whatever you copied into the new image.

Comment: Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/620404/testing-nginx-in-a-docker-container-in-on-ubuntu-core/627317#627317  . The [original screenshot in this answer before I edited it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Czlod.png) was light gray letters on a blue background which I changed to white letters on a black background. If your image is substantially different from my example please provide a link to it and I'll try to do it with your image.